# How to change crystal report template

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have created a custom report template and used this custom template in many report.
Now I have added a new formula and text field in report header of custom report template,
the problem is that this new changes in custom template not showing any of the reports using this custom template.
If any changes done is custom report template it should auto refresh all other reports using this custom template...how it can be done??plz help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Templates don't work the way that you describe--they are NOT linked to any of the other reports.

Instead, a template is applied to a target report; its settings (fields, fonts, etc.) are thus transferred to the target.

You will need to re-apply the templates to the desired reports (as painful as that may be).

** edit **

A template can be applied programmatically using the [report-application server (RAS) SDK](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/RAS_SDK/default.htm).  Review the CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.TemplateEngine assembly.  I believe that RAS is a feature of BusinessObjects Enterprise and Crystal Reports Server only.

** edit 2 **

You could skip the template approach entirely, enumerates a report's object hierarchy, and apply formatting as appropriate.  You could adapt [RptToXml](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/)'s code for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for reply can we re-apply the template from vb6/vb.net code, before preview.

Comment: Will CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.TemplateEngine.dll can work with vb6??

Comment: The RAS SDK does include COM support.  See http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/RAS_SDK/rassdk_com_doc/doc/rassdk_com_doc/Template_Lib9.html#1255434